# Local EJB called through JNDI from different ear method not found

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I'm trying to call a Local EJB from a different ear in which I find the EJB trough JNDI in spring:

```
<jee:local-slsb id="testService"
                jndi-name="ejb/TestService"
                business-interface="com.aaaaa.TestService"
                lookup-home-on-startup="false"/>
```

I have my EJB in ear A:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/TestService")
@Local(TestService.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService
{
     public void test(A a) {....}
}

public interface TestService
{
    void test(A a);
}
```

and I can see that the EJB is found in .ear B, but when trying to call the "test" method the LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor is complaining that it's not able to find the test method:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.aaaaa.TestService$$$view419.test...`

Any idea why this is happening?

Making it @Remote works, but I try to avoid that and find out why with @Local annotation it's not working.